# The (initialdir) in tkinter's filedialog isn't working with a variable

Tags: python, tkinter, filedialog

I'm doing a simple program that moves files, and I'm having it pull the file paths from a text document so it doesn't have to be inputed every time.

Here's the function for one of the buttons:

```
def XboxClick():
     pathfinder = open("settings.txt", "r")
     xboxsavepath = pathfinder.readline()
     steamsavepath = pathfinder.readline()
     pathfinder.close
     #lbl.configure(text=xboxsavepath)
     xboxsavefile = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select the Xbox save", initialdir=xboxsavepath)
```

In the text document, this row is `C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Packages/`.

The commented out line `#lbl.configure(text=xboxsavepath)`  will return `C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Packages/`.

If I do:

```
xboxsavefile = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select the Xbox save", initialdir='C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Packages/')
```

It will open the file window at that directory.

However, when using the variable `xboxsavepath`, which uses the exact same string, it just opens the file window to the default. I don't know why.

Hopefully that's enough info.

Comment: @Cool Cloud yup, `class 'str'`

Comment: It works fine when the trailing newline is stripped after `readline()`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason was quite hard to spot, but it is because there is a newline character at the end of your string because you are using `readline`.

From the docs:

> `f.readline()` reads a single line from the file; a newline character (\n) is left at the end of the string....

If you want to see the newline(\n) then do something like `print(repr(xboxsavepath))`. So, strip the text that you get from the file so the newline character will be removed

```
xboxsavepath = pathfinder.readline().strip()
```

It is also better to strip all the lines you get from the txt, so even if there is an empty line at the end, you don't have to worry about it

---

You also need `pathfinder.close()` with the `()` to execute the method.

Comment: It got rid of \n, but it's still not using it as a directory. When doing `print(repr(xboxsavepath))`, it shows single quotes ('path/path') around xboxsavepath. Doing another `.strip("'")` doesn't appear to fix it. Or maybe that isn't the issue.

Comment: @andrr `repr` will show quotes around the string, it basically shows you how that string would look in your code, you can just copy-paste it and put it in python and it will work fine (unlike if you copy a string that is simply converted to string (just `print(...)`))

Comment: @andrr The thing is, there _WILL_ be \n for each item, I tried this with an example and it fixed the issue for me, can you provide some more information? With \n I dont see a way possible for it to work

Comment: It looks like the problem was from the path having a file at the end of it. `D:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/GameExample/FSD/Saved/SaveGames/76561198207771097_Player.sav` does not work, but `D:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/GameExample/FSD/Saved/SaveGames` does.

Comment: @andrr Oh okay, but in your question you clearly said the label outputs the value just like you need it, and anyway you need `strip()` one way or another.

Comment: @andrr Hi, I hope you found this answer helpful, if so please mark it as correct answer to close this question :)