# Problem setting initialdir in tkinter filedialog askopenfilename

Tags: tkinter, file-handling

I am running tkinter on a nix box but I need my solution to be portable

My initial code to open the file dialog was

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from pathlib import Path

XLS_FILE_TYPES = (
    ('xlsx files', '*.xlsx'),
    ('All files', '*.*')
)

root = tk.Tk()

workbook_path = tk.StringVar(value='home/jeff/Downloads/directors_rota.xlsx')
initialdir = str(Path(workbook_path.get()).parent)
workbook_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    initialdir=initialdir,
    initialfile=str(Path(self.workbook_path.get()).name),
    filetypes=XLS_FILE_TYPES
)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run this the initial file directory is set to the directory from which I run the code

[image]

In order for the initialdir to display correctly I have to adapt the code to manipulate the initialdir string as follows

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from pathlib import Path

XLS_FILE_TYPES = (
    ('xlsx files', '*.xlsx'),
    ('All files', '*.*')
)

root = tk.Tk()

workbook_path = tk.StringVar(value='home/jeff/Downloads/directors_rota.xlsx')

initialdir = str(Path(workbook_path.get()).parent)
home = str(Path.home())[1:]
initialdir = initialdir.replace(home, '~')
workbook_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    initialdir=initialdir,
        initialfile=str(Path(self.workbook_path.get()).name),
    filetypes=XLS_FILE_TYPES
)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Is this expected behaviour?

Will I run into trouble porting to Windows (as a Zippapp)?

There are several questions here that might be related:

[Specify "this pc" as initial dir in tkinter open file popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53566413/specify-this-pc-as-initial-dir-in-tkinter-open-file-popup)

[The (initialdir) in tkinter's filedialog isn't working with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70562954/the-initialdir-in-tkinters-filedialog-isnt-working-with-a-variable)

[tkinter filedialog initialdir is not accepting shell shortcuts. How can I point the dialog to Downloads folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65937161/tkinter-filedialog-initialdir-is-not-accepting-shell-shortcuts-how-can-i-point)

Comment: Missing initial `/` in the path, i.e. it should be `"/home/jeff/..."` instead of `"home/jeff/..."`.